# React-bootstrap modal no longer draggable after migrating to react-bootstrap 2 from 0.33

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I am in the process of migrating my react app from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 5

I was previously using the answer at [how to make react-bootstrap modal draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928675/how-to-make-react-bootstrap-modal-draggable) to make my modal draggable which worked fine (e.g. in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-3-draggable-modal-p9h7h8?file=/src/App.js)) for react-boostrap 0.33 (which supports bootstrap 3)

However I was not able to make them work when using react-bootstrap v2 (which supports bootstrap 5). In both cases I was using `react-draggable: 4.4.4`. This is what I tried:

```
<Draggable handle=".handle">
      <Modal show={show} onHide={toggleShow}>
        <Modal.Header className="handle">
          <Modal.Title>Title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          ...
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </Draggable>
```

This is essentially the same code that I was using before as well but with the library versions (and bootstrap CSS) are updated. There is also a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-5-draggable-modal-4pwprd?file=/src/App.js)

The modal is draggable when using react-bootstrap 0.33 (BS3) but no longer draggable when using react-bootstrap 2 (BS5).

So the question is: how do I make the code that works with react-bootstrap 0.33 and react-draggable, to work with react-bootstrap 2 (in effect).

Answer (score 0):

So as luck would have it I am also using jquery-ui for some legacy parts of the application so I was able to fashion a clumsy solution using that. Here is my draggable modal component:

```
const DraggableModal = (props) => {
  const [node, setNode] = useState(null);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const { onEntered = () => {}, onExited = () => {}, ...modalProps } = props;

  const enteredHandler = useCallback(
    (node, isAppearing) => {
      onEntered(node, isAppearing);
      setNode(window.$(node).find(".modal-dialog")[0]);
      setVisible(true);
    },
    [onEntered]
  );
  const exitedHandler = useCallback(
    (node) => {
      onExited(node);
      setVisible(false);
    },
    [onExited]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if it's mounted
    if (node !== null && visible && !window.$(node).draggable("instance")) {
      window.$(node).draggable({
        handle: ".modal-header",
        scroll: true,
        cursor: "move"
      });
    } else if (
      node !== null &&
      !visible &&
      window.$(node).draggable("instance")
    ) {
      window.$(node).draggable("destroy");
      setNode(null);
    }
  }, [node, visible]);

  return (
    <Modal
      onEntered={enteredHandler}
      onExited={exitedHandler}
      {...modalProps}
    />
  );
};
```

The idea is as soon as the modal enters fully it becomes draggable and when it exists it stops being draggable. I'm not sure if the 2nd part is necessary.

Posting this just in case there is anyone in the unique position to need to make their react-bootstrap modals draggable and also already using jquery-ui for other reasons.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-5-draggable-modal-forked-0uiksw?file=/src/App.js)